# Como fazer tables com BOTÕES com ids diferentes para function javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Estou montando uma table com o seguinte código

```
<table align="center" cellpadding="10" id="user_table" class='table table-striped table-advance table-hover'>
<tr>
<th>NOME</th>
<th>C.P.F.</th>
<th>IDENTIDADE</th>
<th>TEL.</th>
<th>E-MAIL</th>

<th style='text-align: center'>MARCAR</th>
</tr>
<?php
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($select)) 
{
 ?>
 <tr id="row<?php echo $row['id_paciente'];?>">
  <td > <?php echo $row['nome'] . " " . $data_consulta . " " . $id_m_h;?></td>
  <td > <?php echo $row['cpf'];?></td>
  <td > <?php echo $row['identidade'];?></td>
  <td > <?php echo $row['tel_01'];?></td>
  <td > <?php echo $row['email'];?></td>
 
  <td style='text-align: center'>       
    <button id="id_c02b_marcar_consulta" type="button"  class="btn"  value="<?php echo $row['id_paciente']?>" >MARCAR <?php echo $row['id_paciente']?></button>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <?php
}
?>
</table>
```

Como podem notar dentro do WHILE tem a seguinte linha

```
<button id="id_c02b_marcar_consulta" type="button"  class="btn"  value="<?php echo $row['id_paciente']?>" >MARCAR <?php echo $row['id_paciente']?></button>
```

Normalmente eu uso o seguinte código em java script para executar uma ação

```
$('#id_c02b_marcar_consulta').click(function () 
            {               
            funcao_patati_patata($("#id_c02b_marcar_consulta").val(),"<?php $id_usuario; ?>","<?php $id_horario; ?>"); 
            });
```

Como estou em uma TABLE e os IDs ESTÃO IGUAIS... o código acima só ira funcionar para a primeira linha.
Minha ideia é cada BOTÃO na linha da table tem que gravar um registro contendo id_usuario, id_paciente, id_horario. Já tenho todas as variáveis carregadas.
**Não tenho muita experiencia em PHP/JAVASCRIPT/JQUERY então não estou vendo um outro caminho para o meu problema.**  ***Fazer uma funçao javascript que atenda todas as linhas da table***
Com meu conhecimento atual eu teria que ter uma função javascript para cada botão da linha da table.  Não é uma opção pois a table é dinâmica e vem da base de dados.

Answer (score 1):

Pra disparar a mesma função em vários elementos eles precisam ser identificados por classnames.

No HTML:

```
   <button id="id_c02b_marcar_consulta" type="button"  class="id_c02b_marcar_consulta btn"  value="<?php echo $row['id_paciente']?>" >MARCAR <?php echo $row['id_paciente']?></button>
```

E no evento:

```
$('.id_c02b_marcar_consulta').click(function (){console.log('fui clicado')})
```

Comment: Boa tarde.. cara.. foi a resposta mais rápida que já tive.. Nem o "SIM" da minha esposa no casamento foi rápido assim :).  Entendi a IDEIA que tu falou mas com meu pequeno conhecimento não entendi o lance da classe. O button têm uma classe... Eu teria que fazer uma outra classe com ALGO especial?? diferente?? Demorei mais escrevendo essas linha que a pergunta em si :)

Comment: Não muda absolutamente nada, apenas vai usar class em vez de usar o id, e o seletor de classname é '.' (ponto) o do id é '#' (hashtag), entendeu ? só mudar o que você usar em id='' para dentro do class='', você pode ter quantas classnames quiser, só separar por espaço um do outro.

Answer (score 1):

Vou me ater ao problema no seu script.

O problema é que ID's devem ser únicos na sua página. Sendo assim, ao consultar um nó por ID, apenas um valor será retornado. É nesse ponto que entram as classes css. Classes podem ser repetidas em seus nós, e retornam múltiplos valores quando consultadas.

Sendo assim, você poderia adicionar uma classe ao atributo class do botão, que ficaria:

```
<button type="button" class="btn marcar-consulta"></button>
```

Com a classe em posição você poderia fazer algo como:

```
$(".marcar-consulta").on("click", function(){
    funcao_que_marca_consulta($(this).val());
});
```

P.S.: Não acho que deveria misturar código PHP com o código JavaScript.

Comment: Boa tarde.. Entendi a sua explicação e a do AnthraxisBR.  Mais tarde irei testar esse modo.  Enquanto esperava uma luz dos colegas do forum, tive uma ideia.. No button colocar o ONCLIC e no nesse evento estou tentando colocar a seguinte funaçao que vem de um arquivo de .js : marcar_consulta(<?php echo $row['id_paciente']?>, <?php echo $id_m_h?>).  Assim que terminar... Vou fazer do modo que vocês indicaram.  De qualquer maneira.. demora bastante.. esse lance de php tem que escrever muuuuiiitoooo. Abraços e obrigado.